# the person of someone

Tags: meaning

Source: [20 detained in plot to assassinate Chechen leader Kadyrov](https://www.rt.com/politics/320609-20-detained-over-plot-to/)

Example:

> “Even though the detained considered themselves supporters of the Islamic State, they did not have even remote understanding about **the person of the extremist leader Abu-Bakr al-Baghdadi**. They had their brains polluted by some undereducated so-called imam and they were taught to hate the head of the Chechen Republic as the main enemy of the Wahhabi ideology,” Kadyrov wrote on his Instagram account, which he uses as his main tool for communication with the public.

How exactly do you understand that? Give examples, please.

Comment: Hi cookie guy! Please write clear titles. If you ever wondered how, take a look at [this not-so-short tutorial](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/q/2630/) whenever you got the time. Most of your titles are the phrase that has caused the confusion, but please at least indicate what part of the phrase and from what aspect (comprehension, articles etc.) is confusing. For instance, I'd suggest you edit this question's title to be *How can I understand "the person of someone" used in a news article?"*. Thanks for understanding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*person* used here is similar in meaning to "who he really is". You don't just *understand* him as a third party observer, but have a deeper understanding of who he is.

See these definitions - [***person***](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/person)

> 3b) bodily form or appearance"   ⇒ to be neat about one's person"
>   4) personality; self; being